# For loop cannot distinguish * syntax

Tags: bash, shell-script, wildcards

```
set -x 
for f in ~/1/2/*/*_1.txt; do
subdir="${f%/*}"
pushd "$subdir" &>/dev/null
file="${f##*/}"

expTool INPUT1= "${f##*/}" INPUT2= "${f%_1.txt}_2.txt OUTPUT1= "${f%_1.txt}_3.txt" OUTPUT2= "${f%_2.txt}_4.txt"
done

expTool error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '*_1.txt'
```

I have subtracted the quotations, but it was a no go.

EDIT: With set -x

```
+for f in '/User/admin/1/2/*/*_1.txt'
+subdir='/User/admin/1/2/*'
+pushd '/User/admin/1/2/*'
+file='*_1.txt'
+expTool INPUT= '*_1.txt' OUTPUT= '${f%_1.txt}_2.txt'
```

So it looks like the '*' syntax is not being registered as a wildcard(?). I am using Mac OSX 10.8.6.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35347/discussion-on-question-by-mattqdean-for-loop-cannot-distinguish-syntax).

Comment: OS/X comes with zsh. You don't have to use bash there.

Answer (score 1):

Either you ran `set -f` earlier in the script, which disables wildcard expansion, or there are no matching files. If there are no matching files, the pattern is left unchanged, so the for loop runs on one element which is the unchanged pattern. In bash, you can use `shopt -s nullglob` to make non-matching patterns instead expand to the empty list.

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure that i understand your code,

```
for f in ~/1/2/*/*_1.txt; do
  fdn="${f%/*}"
  fbn1="${f##*/}"
  fbn2="${fbn1//_1/_2}"
  fbn3="${fbn1//_1/_3}"
  fbn4="${fbn1//_1/_4}"
  expTool INPUT1= "$fdn/$fbn1" INPUT2= "$fdn/$fbn2" OUTPUT1= "$fdn/$fbn3" OUTPUT2= "$fdn/$fbn4"
done
```

if i am of toppic please let me know  , i delete my answer!